# Specify that a method needs a mutex held when calling

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex

## Current situation

Right now I have a method like

```
  Data lookupData(Key id)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    auto it = m_dict.find(id);
    if(it == m_dict.end())
    {
      return Data::Empty;
    }
    else
    {
      return it->second;
    }
  }
```

## Problem

However I now have a situation where, if the result is not found, I want the calling code to be able to do some more stuff *while keeping the lock held*.

One straightforward solution is to take the mutex lock outside of this method and require calling code to lock the mutex instead, maybe by documenting this in a doc comment or something.  However it feels like it would be better to be able to *enforce* this, by passing some kind of receipt to the method proving that we actually hold a lock on the mutex in question.

## Potential solution(s)

So I'm considering doing something like

```
  Data lookupData(Key id, const std::unique_lock<std::mutex> & lock)
  {
    if(lock.mutex() != m_mutex) { /* throw * }
    if(! lock.owns_lock()) { /* throw */ }

    auto it = m_dict.find(id);
    if(it == m_dict.end())
    {
      return Data::Empty;
    }
    else
    {
      return it->second;
    }
  }
```

Alternatively instead of

```
     if(! lock.owns_lock()) { /* throw */ }
```

I could do something like

```
     if(! lock.owns_lock()) { lock.lock(); }
```

(obviously removing the `const` qualifier from the `lock` parameter) so that the method can be called either with or without the lock being held.

## Questions

- Is the idea of a method requiring proof that a mutex is locked a good one, or if not, why not?
- Assuming the answer to the above is "yes," are the above approaches recommended?  If not, why not, and what would be recommended instead?
- Are there names for the type of problem and/or the general solutions described above that I can Google to read more about this sort of thing?

Comment: Could you make your lock reentrant, and lock from the caller of the function and from the function as well?

Comment: Have you considered recursive mutexes? Those can be locked multiple times by one thread.

Comment: I haven't heard of recursive_mutex before.  It's an interesting idea but (without any experience with them) sounds like it could easily open up a whole can of worms by letting people handle mutexes fairly lazily.

Comment: Concurrency is indeed hard, but the usage of reentrant locks is quite widespread when the use case warrants it. I think what could also be helpful to answer your question is to have a more practical example of why you need the caller to hold the lock, and how the `lookupData` method is intended to be used (Can it be called from other classes?).

Comment: You should always, always hold a mutex for the minimum time possible. Look for recursive mutexes, and lock if you have a try lock functionality in your programming environment. Checking whether a mutex is locked and then locking it is unsafe.

Comment: Daniel, lazy is good for software developers.

Answer (score 2):

One solution here is to create a proxy object for the API that should only be available while locked. Something like this:

```
class Dict
{
  std::mutex m_mutex;
  std::unordered_map<Key, Data> m_dict;
public:
  class Lock
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_lock;
    Dict* m_parent;
  public:
    explicit Lock(Dict& parent)
      : m_lock(parent.m_mutex),
        m_parent(&parent)
    {}
    Data lookup(Key key)
    {
      auto it = m_parent->m_dict.find(id);
      return it == m_parent->m_dict.end() ? Data::Empty : it->second;
    }
  };
  Lock lock()
  { return Lock(*this); }
};

int main()
{
  Dict d;
  d.lock().lookup(0);
  auto locked = d.lock();
  if(locked.lookup(1))
    locked.lookup(2);
}
```